# How to create operation loop for two 1 to 1 lists

Tags: python, loops

Say I have 2 lists:

```
A = [a1,a2,a3,...,an]
B = [b1,b2,b3,...,bn]
```

The lists are one-to-one.

So how do I create a loop that operates (any operation):

```
a1 with b1
a2 with b2
...
an with bn
```

Comment: Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).  If you had some function `add` and lists `l1 = [1, 2, 3]`, `l2 = [4, 5, 6]` then `[add(a, b) for a, b in zip(l1, l2)]` would be `[5, 7, 9]`.  The `[_ for _ in _]` is called a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your lists are one-to-one, then they must both be the same size. In this case [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) is the best option here. This function makes an iterator and aggregates elements into tuple pairs from each of the iterables:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = [5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> zipped = zip(a, b)
>>> print(list(zipped))
[(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8)]
>>> print(tuple(zipped))
((1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8))
```

This means that you can apply a function on each of the tuples within the zipped iterable:

```
>>> print([sum(x) for x in zipped])
[6, 8, 10, 12]
>>> print([max(x) for x in zipped])
[5, 6, 7, 8]
```

You can also achieve similar behavior with [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = [5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> print(list(map(lambda x, y : x + y, a, b)))
[6, 8, 10, 12]
>>> print(list(map(lambda x, y : x * y, a, b)))
[5, 12, 21, 32]
```

I'd also suggest writing a `zip()` function with iterators to see how it works:

```
def my_zip(seq1, seq2):
    i1 = iter(seq1)
    i2 = iter(seq2)
    while True:
        yield next(i1), next(i2)
```

Additionally, another less preferred way would be to loop over the first list, and use the indices to also access the elements in the second list:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = [5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> for i in range(len(a)):
        print(a[i], b[i])
1 5
2 6
3 7
4 8
>>> print([a[i] + b[i] for i in range(len(a))])
[6, 8, 10, 12]
```

This is not very pythonic, but it also works. I recommend using `zip()` over this.

Answer (score 2):

Use [**zip**](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip)

```
a = [1,2,3];
b = [4,5,6];

for x,y in zip(a,b):
    print x,y;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to process:

```
for ea, eb in zip(A, B):
    f(ea, eb)
```

If you want to keep results,

```
[f(ea, eb) for ea, eb in zip(A, B)]
```

The `zip` builtin sews together two or more lists elementwise into a list of tuples that we can then iterate on, either by an explicit loop or by a comprehension.